# html combo box or select box for multiple selection

Tags: html, codeigniter

[image]I am just wondering what's the name of the below form? I was Googling from morning for the list of HTML forms but I couldn't find this kind of form anywhere. Can anyone tell me the exact name of this form and is this available in HTML forms?

I just want to add this kind of form in my website. Is that available for HTML or should I use JavaScript or its only limited for Windows applications? can someone help me please

Answer (score 7):

For multi-select combo-box, you can use **multiple** attribute.

```
<select name="items" multiple>
<option value="">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Then based on your first screen-shot, to add items from one combo to another you should use some JavaScript.Below is the full html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        select, input[type="text"] {
           width: 160px;
           box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        section {
           padding: 8px;
           background-color: #f0f0f0;
           overflow: auto;
        }
        section > div {
          float: left;
          padding: 4px;
        }
        section > div + div {
          width: 40px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        fieldset {
            padding:10px;margin-top:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="container">
    <div>
        <select id="leftValues" size="5" multiple>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <!--div>
            <input type="text" id="txtLeft" />
        </div-->
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
        <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="rightValues" size="4" multiple>

        </select>
        <!--div>
            <input type="text" id="txtRight" />
        </div-->
    </div>
</section>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Descriptive Options</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Your content here -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="mean" checked> Mean
        <input type="checkbox" name="sum"> Sum
        <fieldset style="padding:10px;margin-top:10px;">
            <legend>Description</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" checked> Std. Deviation
            <input type="checkbox"> Minimum
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Help</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#btnLeft").click(function () {
        var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
        $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
    });

    $("#btnRight").click(function () {
        var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
        $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
    });

    $("#rightValues").change(function () {
        //var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
        //$("#txtRight").val(selectedItem.text());
    });
    $("#leftValues").change(function () {
        //var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
        //$("#txtLeft").val(selectedItem.text());
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TyHzX/)**

Comment: i devo i have added the code i used in above can you please help me thanks

Comment: i have used as follows jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/3 but i need to be placed them in opposite way that is combo box multi select on left side and the selected values in right side now am getting in opposite way can you help me please.

Comment: Check my updated answer.It's for simple use, you can add more conditions in the JavaScript.

Comment: thanks a lot and as you have seen the image when they click on option after selecting it has to show another div with checkboxes to select. is it possible.

Comment: This can be done using bootstrap model or jquery-ui. Please check my updated answer using twitter bootstrap. Here is the bootstrap model documentation. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals